# Where are the hidden ingredients?

Tags: witcheye

Each world in Witcheye has one hidden ingredient (in addition to the one you get from defeating the boss). Unfortunately, there's no easy way to even figure out which *level* in the world has the ingredient, so it can be really tedious to search the entire world several times over if you keep missing it.

Which levels have the ingredients, and how can I find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** According to [Funtime Mike](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/358729/86987) the location of the ingredients differs between the various difficulty levels. This answer only applies to normal difficulty.

I wasn't able to find any information online about these yet, much less a spoiler-free hint list. I kept at it though and found all of them myself, so I figured I'd create such a list. For each world, there are three levels of hints: the level it's in, a hint about how to find it, and then the exact location. I imagine the second hint will give it away most of the time though.

## World 1: Mabel's Cave

> 1–5 Rockslide

> One of the titular rock slides is not like the others.

> The penultimate rock slide has a suspicious cave background behind the top-most tiles. You can go out of bounds here and pick up the hidden bone.

## World 2: Dark Forest

> 2–8 Mystery Grove

> You'll need to check behind a suspicious platform.

> Right below the exit arrow, there's a small square of platform that's oddly separated from the surrounding platform. This platform is actually in the foreground and the mushroom is hidden behind it.

## World 3: Ocean

> 3–5 Abyssal Plain

> The ingredient is well guarded.

> If you kill the last shooting eye in the level you can actually go behind the wall that it covered and find the pearl there.

## World 4: Ruins of the Sky City

> 4–2 Hanging Gardens

> Watch out for suspicious ceiling decoration.

> In the final corridor, near the exit arrow, one ceiling tile doesn't have any vines on it. The feather is behind that tile.

## World 5: Fields of Fire

> 5–6 Forge

> It's not actually the lava that kills you...

> ...it's the bubbles. And one pool of lava (the penultimate one) doesn't bubble. That's where the clover leaf is hidden.

## World 6: Senexis' Tower

> 6–4 Innocuous Corridor

> You'll need to go out of bounds.

> The nook that the pumpkin hides in is accessible. You'll find the... obsidian?... in the centre of it. Don't get eaten while trying to grab it. ;)